# Selecting mutiple random sequences of N elements from M different-length lists in Python

Tags: python, combinations, probability

I have X lists of elements, each list containing a different number of elements (without repetitions inside a single list). I want to generate (if possible, 500) sequences of 3 elements, where each element belongs to a different list, and sequences do not repeat. So something like:

X (in this case 4) lists of elements: [A1,A2], [B1,B2,B3,B4], [C1], [D1,D2,D3,D4,D5]

possible results: [A1,B2,D2], [B3,C1,D2], [A1,B2,C1]... (here 500 sequences are impossible, so would be less)

I think I know how to do it with a nasty loop: join all the lists, random.sample(len(l),3) from the joint list, if 2 indices belong to the same list repeat, if not, check if the sequence was not found before. But that would be very slow. I am looking for a more pythonic or more mathematically clever way.

Perhaps a better way would be to use random.sample([A,B,C,D], 3, p=[len(A), len(B), len(C), len(D)]), then for each sequence from it randomly select an element from each group in the sequence, then check if a new sequence generated in this way hasn't been generated before. But again, a lot of looping.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check `itertools` module (combination and permutation in particular).
You can get a `random.choice()` from the permutations of 3 elements from the X lists (thus selecting 3 lists), and for each of them get a `random.choice()` (random module).

Comment: I think this may be equivalent to my "second" method, however, itertools do not allow for providing any probability distributions, so my permutations of lists would not reflect how many elements is in each of them...

Comment: If you want to weight the choice by the list length, then you can use np.choice() rather than random.choice(). This allows to set probability distributions.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Comment: Thanks, but one of the problems is that np.random.choice does not allow for generating N sets, where in each set elements do not repeat, but can repeat between sets. In general, it does not generate permutations without repetition...

Comment: Run it 3 times removing the selected list from the set on each iteration